# Ошибка в записи в файл (рейтинговый бот) discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я начал очередную попытку написать бота для рейтинга, вот код:

**xp_bot.py:**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import json
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await client.send_message(channel, '{} has leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end

client.run('token')
```

**users.json (изначально):**

```
{
    
}
```

**В файл "users.json" должны записываться xp и lvl:**

```
{"702338551806951466": {"experience": 5,10,15 и т.д, "level": 1,2,3 и т.д}}
```

Но когда мы отправляем 2-ое сообщение, вместо того, чтобы прибавить xp или lvl, он записывает тоже самое:

```
{"702338551806951466": {"experience": 5, "level": 1}, "702338551806951466": {"experience": 5, "level": 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас ключи одинаковые. Потому они не добавляются, а перезаписываются. Можно попробовать добавить индекс. Для примера:

```
idu = "702338551806951466"
d = dict()
d[idu] = dict()

k = {"experience": 5, "level": 1}
j = {"experience": 4, "level": 1}

d[idu].update({'0': k})
d[idu].update({'1': j})
```

Теперь, если вы распечатаете d, результат будет:
{'702338551806951466': {'0': {'experience': 5, 'level': 1}, '1': {'experience': 4, 'level': 1}}}

Comment: Можно подробнее ответ, как и где использовать?

Comment: Вам нужно попробовать добавить счетчик, который будет увеличиваться при каждом обращении к функции. Для начала формировать данные, которые вы хотите добавить. То есть, например, у вас счетчик count = 2. Формируете словарь: experience = {"experience": 5, "level": 1}, а потом обновляете: users[user.id].update({count: experience}). Таким образом, при следующем обращении счетчик увеличиться и у вас добавиться новое значение, а не перезапишется. Наверное как-то так.

Comment: спасибо, уже решил проблему

Comment: Да не за что ))